# how to remove base gatsby style from safari (purple bg)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari, mobile-safari

[cant change purple background to white background on iPhone and mac header in safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhFvQ.png)

i make site using gatsby with react and when i test it in safari i see purple background an now i want make it white like in google chrome
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhFvQ.png)

need to change this color but don't know where i can change this
`background: #5f3797`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is most likely the meta element with theme-color, for example:

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#5f3797">
```

The color is potentially set in gatsby-config.js if you used the gatsby-starter-default.

See more here: https://css-tricks.com/meta-theme-color-and-trickery/